# commandlink primefaces with href

Tags: primefaces

i'm trying to open a popup mailto by using two different codes:

```
(1)- <p:link  href="mailto:#{classManagedBean.sendEmails}" />

(2)- <p:commandlink actionListener="#{candidatManagedBean.sendEmails()}" />
```

the "senEmails" is a method declared in the classManagedBean in order to get all the selected emails when a submit of the form done.

The issus that i encountred that when:

- working with the code (1) the selected mails came to the managedBean with null values and a popup of the mail interface open with empty mails (as destination)
- with the code (2) the selected mails came with the correct values but the popup didn't appear (beacause there is no href attribut!! in the commandLink)

My question is how can i use a

```
<p:link> with a submit form
```

`<p:commandLink> with href attribut`

The Xhtml:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:link href="#{candidatManagedBean.createmaito()}">
        <p:graphicImage width="25" value="ecrire.png"  height="25" alt="envoyer"/>
    </p:link>
</h:form> 



     <p:dataTable id="listCandidat"  
                  value="#{candidatManagedBean.listCandidat}"
                             emptyMessage="0 candidat trouvé" 
                             var="item" 
                             paginator="true" rows="15" paginatorPosition="bottom" 
                             rowKey="#{item.idCandidat}"
                             paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"  
                             lazy="true"
                             selection="#{candidatManagedBean.selectedCandidates}"
                             >
    
    
        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{candidatManagedBean.onRowSelect}" />
    
        <p:column exportable="false" selectionMode="multiple" style="width:16px;text-align:center"/>                     
        
        {<p:column>...</p:column>}           
    
    </p:dataTable>
```

The managedBean:

```
public String createmaito() { //  private List<Candidat> selectedCandidates;
      
        System.out.println(selectedCandidates);//here i got a null value of selectedCandidates
        if (selectedCandidates != null && !selectedCandidates.isEmpty()) {
            for (Candidat cand : selectedCandidates) {
                lsEmail = lsEmail.concat(cand.getEmail1());
                lsEmail = lsEmail.concat(",");
            }
          lsEmail=  lsEmail.substring(0, lsEmail.length()-1);          
          result =  lsEmail;
            
         
        } 
        else {            
          result = "";
        }       
        return result;
}
```

Comment: focus on `p:link` but also create an [mcve] and focus on why it is null. Your question title indicates you are trying to solve a second problem which you think is the solution to your original one.

Comment: I tried to edit my question in order to be more specifique. Can you have another look!

Comment: Your question is clear, that was not the problem. Your questions on how to submit a form on a `p:link` or have an `href` on the  `p:commandButton`, both totally approach the problem from the wrong way. Look into using ajax when selecting the row and updating the `p:link`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution as follows:

-In XHTML:

```
<p:commandLink   actionListener="#{ManagedBean.getListeOfEmailContacts()}">
    <p:graphicImage  value="/mail.png" />
</p:commandLink>
```

-In managed bean:

```
public void getListeOfEmailContacts() {
    /* instruction to get the ListOfContacts ...*/

    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("window.open(href ='mailto:" + ListOfContacts + "')"); 
 }
```